# RelativeSource binding from a ToolTip or ContextMenu

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, relativesource

What am I doing wrong here?:

```
 <GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Button>
            <Button.ToolTip>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}" />
```

That's just a simplified example, that doesn't work anyway :) 
Actually I need to get a value from another property that is in scope of the Window's DataContext.

Help me pls.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

This is tricky because ToolTip is not part of the VisualTree. [Here](http://blog.jtango.net/binding-to-a-menuitem-in-a-wpf-context-menu) you see a cool solution for the same problem with ContextMenus. The same way you can go for the ToolTip.

**UPDATE**
Sadly the link is gone and I have not found the referenced article anymore.
As far as I remember, the referenced blog has shown how to bind to a DataContext of another VisualTree, which is often necessay when binding from a ToolTip, a ContextMenu or a Popup.

A nice way to do this, is to provide the desired instance (e.g. ViewModel) within the Tag-property of the PlacementTarget. The following example does this for accessing a Command-instance of a ViewModel:

```
<Button Tag="{Binding DataContext,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}}">
  <Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
       <MenuItem Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.DesiredCommand,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ContextMenu}}" .../>
    <ContextMenu>
  </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

*I have not tested it and its a long time I did this the last time. Please make a comment if it does not work for you.*

**UPDATE 2**

As the original link that this answer was written about is gone, I hit archive.org and [found the original blog entry](http://web.archive.org/web/20101207234603/http://blog.jtango.net/2008/10/29/binding-to-a-menuitem-in-a-wpf-context-menu/). Here it is, verbatim from the blog:

> Because a ContextMenu in WPF does not exist within the visual tree of
>   your page/window/control per se, data binding can be a little tricky.
>   I have searched high and low across the web for this, and the most
>   common answer seems to be “just do it in the code behind”. WRONG! I
>   didn’t come in to the wonderful world of XAML to be going back to
>   doing things in the code behind.
>
> Here is my example to that will allow you to bind to a string that
>   exists as a property of your window.
>
> ```
> public partial class Window1 : Window
> {
>     public Window1()
>     {
>         MyString = "Here is my string";
>     }
>
>     public string MyString
>     {
>         get;
>         set;
>
>     }
> }
>
>
> <Button Content="Test Button" 
>      Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}">
>   <Button.ContextMenu>
>     <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, 
>           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
>       <MenuItem Header="{Binding MyString}"/>
>     </ContextMenu>
>   </Button.ContextMenu>   
> </Button>
> ```
>
> The important part is the Tag on the button(although you could just as
>   easily set the DataContext of the button). This stores a reference to
>   the parent window. The ContextMenu is capable of accessing this
>   through it’s PlacementTarget property. You can then pass this context
>   down through your menu items.
>
> I’ll admit this is not the most elegant solution in the world.
>   However, it beats setting stuff in the code behind. If anyone has an
>   even better way to do this I’d love to hear it.

Comment: @Bill I have not found the link anymore but I have tried to explain the way how the problem can be resolved.

Comment: Massively helpful and much simpler than the 'namescope hack' solutions that put me off using contextmenus and tooltips previously. This is disgustingly simple and works perfectly.

Comment: @ChrisValentine Feel free to mess with my edit; I just wanted to make sure the original solution was recorded here.

Answer (score 6):

Per below:
PlacementTarget is the control that owns the ContextMenu (ex: DataGrid).  No need for a "tag" property.

IsEnabled binds to the DataGrid's "myProperty" value.

I tested this and it works.  Was having similar issue with binding.

```
<ContextMenu
DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
IsEnabled="{Binding myProperty}"  
>
```

Answer (score -1):

Because `ContextMenu` is not in visual tree, binding will not work.
a simple solution is using Proxy Pattern, you can create a wrapper class that inherits from `DependencyObject` and has a `DependencyProperty` that will keep a `DataContext` of your `Window`, then you can have a resource of the proxy in XAML and finally bind your `MenuItem` command to your desired command via the proxy object.
**Sample Proxy:**

```
Public class ProxyClass : DependencyObject
{
    Public object Data {get; set;}
   public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DataProperty", typeof(object), typeof(ProxyClass), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

**How to use in XAML:**

```
<Window DataContext="{Binding MyViewModel}">
...
<Window.Resources>
    <ProxyClass Data={Binding} x:Key="BindingProxy"/>

</Window.Resources>
...  
<MenuItem Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource BindingProxy}, Path=Data.MyDesiredCommand"/>
...
</Window>
```

**What is happening?**
`Data` property of `ProxyClass` will bind to `DataContext` of `Window`, then it has all of your comamnds and properties of your `ViewModel` inside the `ProxyClass` resource.
another benefit of this approach is portability and re-using in multiple views and projects.

Comment: this approach can be use only on the same window xaml code

Comment: @TuanTran what do you mean exactly of "only on the same window xaml code"?

Comment: You cannot split the ```<Window.Resources>...</Window.Resources>``` part to a separated resource file

Answer (score -3):

I think it should be done like this:

```
{Binding Path=Title, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

Comment: This works not because the main VisualTree is not available from the ToolTip. See my answer.

Comment: yah sorry, didn't actually even notice that it was within a tooltip.