# WPF Bind to Element From ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I've defined class trigger which implements the `TriggerAction<UIElement>`.
Inside that class I would like to access the parent of the context menu which is of `ContentControl` type.
So I've defined `DependencyProperty` of type: `ContentControl`inside the trigger class.

```
public class MoveToEditModeTrigger : TriggerAction<UIElement>
    {
        protected override void Invoke(object parameter)
        {
            if (ContentControl == null) return;
            Selector.SetIsSelected(ContentControl, false);
            ContentControl.Focusable = true;
        }

        public ContentControl ContentControl
        {
            get { return (ContentControl)GetValue(ContentControlProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ContentControlProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentControlProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("ContentControl", typeof(ContentControl), typeof(MoveToEditModeTrigger), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
```

Here is the `ContextMenu` inside the `ContentControl` which I want to access from the trigger class:

```
<ContentControl Name="contentControl">
  <ContentControl.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem Header="EditText">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
          <trigger:MoveToEditModeTrigger ContentControl="{Binding ElementName=contentControl}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
      </MenuItem>
     </ContextMenu>
  </ContentControl.ContextMenu>
<RichTextBox x:Name="richtxtLeft" Focusable="True" />
</ContentControl>
```

The problem is that the binding fail, the `ContentControl` dependency property remains null.
I've done that too without success:

```
ContentControl="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl, Mode=FindAncestor}}"
```

And also tried to use `VisualTreeHalper` to find the `ContentControl`.
I've also tried to bind to the `RichTextBox` inside the `ContentControl` but without any result.

Please, how can I access the `ContentControl` within the trigger class?

Comment: The context menu is not in the visual tree of your UI. It is "flying over" your UI and has its own visual tree.

Comment: I understand, how can I bind from it's visual tree to another control in my UI?

Comment: You need to bind to the PlacementTarget property of the ContextMenu.  That is the route by which elements in the context menu can reach the visual tree.  Often, if you need to get to a specific element, the Tag property is used as a temporary storage for the element in order to make binding simpler.  [I believe this is the canonical question on the subject](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668654/relativesource-binding-from-a-tooltip-or-contextmenu).  If it answers your question, we can mark this as a duplicate (no worries about that). If not, [edit] and state why.

Comment: Thank you very nuch ! Yes this is a duplicate question, we can mark is as duplicate. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the context menu, adorners, tooltips, and other elements are not  in the application's visual tree, they are in some other layer. For solving this, what I try to do, is to to make the bindings using the datacontext, to make the bindings to the view model, this view model could be the menu's view model (datacontext), or window's view model, maybe the `MainViewModel` etc.

In this way you could have a list or observable collection with, maybe, `MenuViewModel`s (with a property `IsSelected`), and an item in the main view model named `SelectedMenu` or some thing like that. And change the items templates, or data templates according the view models values/data. Hope this tips help.