# Binding Error : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a customized Textbox which has some property SelfPropertyInfo(which further has some property like IsValid and RuleDescription).

I am trying to add below style on every Textbox of this type.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CustomControls:TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,2,2"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
                </Trigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelfPropertyInfo.IsValid}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" >
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ToolTip >                                
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type CustomControls:TextBox},AncestorLevel=2},Path=SelfPropertyInfo.RuleDescription}"/>
                             </ToolTip>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

In above code I am not getting Tooltip Text. (Result of below code)

```
<TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type CustomControls:TextBox},AncestorLevel=2},Path=SelfPropertyInfo.RuleDescription}"/>
```

I am getting below error:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with
>   reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
>   AncestorType='CustomControls.TextBox', AncestorLevel='2''.
>   BindingExpression:Path=SelfPropertyInfo.RuleDescription;
>   DataItem=null; target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'Text' (type 'String')

Can anybody suggest the mistake I did in Text binding?

Note: I can't change the way Tooltip is added :(

Comment: Do you need `AncestorLevel` in there?

Comment: Does it work if you remove the AncestorLevel? Are you sure it's level 2?

Comment: It also doesn't work if I remove AncestorLevel :(

Comment: @AKP Here is an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3668699/4049478 The tooltip is not part of the visual tree

Comment: It doesn't work. See what I did:
1. Added a setter - `<Setter Property="Tag" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=SelfPropertyInfo.RuleDescription}"/>`
2. Set DataContext of tooltip : `<ToolTip DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=PlacementTarget.Tag}">`
3. Changed the TextBlock's text: `<TextBlock  Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=SelfPropertyInfo.RuleDescription}"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would like to say thanks to [nkoniishvt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4049478/nkoniishvt) for this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668654/relativesource-binding-from-a-tooltip-or-contextmenu/3668699#3668699). It helped me to understand the problem. By using below code it worked as expected:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type CustomControls:TextBox}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="22"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,2,2,2"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
                </Trigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=SelfPropertyInfo.IsValid}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red"/>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Tag" Value= "{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ToolTip Height="28" Background="Red" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},Path=PlacementTarget.Tag}">
                                <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Path=SelfPropertyInfo.RuleDescription}"/>
                            </ToolTip>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>
```