# Custom control: binding in ItemContainerStyle

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I'm working in a Explorer tree view (custom wpf control designed by me). I have this code in **Generic.xaml:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ExplorerControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ExplorerControl}">
                <Border> 
                        <TreeView Name="myTreeView" >                              
                            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">                                       
                                    <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ContextMenu>
                                            <MenuItem x:Name="myTemplate" Header="Remove" Command="{TemplateBinding  RemoveCommand}"></MenuItem>
                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                          
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        </TreeView> 
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In **ExplorerControl** I have my Dependency Property:

```
public class ExplorerControl : Control{

    public ExplorerControl()
    {
        Nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
    } 

    private ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; }

    public ICommand RemoveCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(RemovedCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(RemovedCommandProperty, value); }
    }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RemovedCommandProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("RemoveCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(ExplorerControl));
}
```

**Node class**

```
public class Node {
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

**My problem is that I don't know how to get that the MenuItem Command works**

I have tried these:

1. If I use the same code with a button after the TreeView (with both in a Stackpanel) it works. So I think that the problem is the MenuItem DataContext
2. I tried to change the MenuItem DataContext however I didn't get it.

I hope you can help me.

**Edit**: I delete the part of code about DataContext. Thanks for you answers.

I use this control in my MainView:

```
   <treeViewExplorerControl:ExplorerControl                                    
   SelectedItemName="{Binding SelectedItemName}"
   SelectedItemPath="{Binding SelectedItemPath}"                                
   RemoveCommand="{Binding ExplorerControlItemRemovedCommand}"/>
```

Comment: Note that setting a ExplorerControl as TreeView.DataContext creates a new ExplorerControl instance. That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Clemens thanks I'm a bit new with custom controls. I removed that part of code.

Comment: Is the last piece of code in a Window? I'm lost as to how your solution looks like to duplicate it.

Comment: @AzzamAziz I have two projects, One is the custom control called treeViewExplorerControl, the other is a WPF project, in the WPF project I use in my MainView.xaml the ExplorerControl with the last piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

First of all I found that about ContextMenu:

> Because a ContextMenu in WPF does not exist within the visual tree of your page/window/control per se, data binding can be a little tricky.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3668699/5684370)

With the example, I wrote this code and I got that it works well:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ExplorerControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ExplorerControl}">
                    <Border>
                        <TreeView Name="myTreeView">
                            <TreeView.Resources>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FF003BB0" />
                            </TreeView.Resources>
                            <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                                    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True" />
                                </Style>
                            </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                                Tag="{Binding TemplatedParent,RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type TreeView}}}">                                      
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                        <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                                            <ContextMenu>
                                                <MenuItem x:Name="myTemplate"
                                                          Header="Remove"
                                                          DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"
                                                          Command="{Binding Path=Tag.RemoveCommand}"
                                                          CommandParameter="{Binding Path=DataContext}">                                    
                                                </MenuItem>
                                            </ContextMenu>
                                        </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                        </TreeView>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**I save in the Stackpanel tag, the reference of my explorerControl, then I use PlacementTarget to get the Stackpanel reference**

I hope this code helps other people in future.

Answer (score 1):

### Proposed Solution:

In your `MenuItem` `Commands` try using Ancestral Binding.

```
<MenuItem x:Name="myTemplate" Header="Remove"
          Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Path=RemoveCommand, AncestorType={x:Type ExplorerControl}, Mode=FindAncestor" />
```

I believe the reason your `DataContext` is changing is because you're pointing to `Nodes` and showing each `Node` in the `MenuItem`. However, `Node` does not contain the command you are trying to bind to.

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">                                          
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

If you are unsure of your `DataContext` you can use Snoop to see what is the current DataContext.

### Extra Info:

I don't think you need to point `DataContext` of your `TreeView`. It's passed down automatically.

```
<TreeView.DataContext>
    <local:ExplorerControl x:Name="explorer" />
</TreeView.DataContext>
```

You don't have to use a `DependencyProperty` with an `ICommand`. In the constructor of your `ExplorerControl` you can instantiate the `ICommand` to a `DelegateCommand`.

1. Make a `DelegateCommand` class that inherits from `ICommand`. This will be your concrete implementation of `ICommand`. You can find that here:http://www.wpftutorial.net/delegatecommand.html
2. Instantiate your `ICommands` with a `DelegateCommand` and pass your method, that is on `ExplorerControl`, to the constructor.

For example:

```
public class ExplorerControl : UserControl
{
    public DelegateCommand RemoveCommand { get; set; }

    public ExplorerControl()
    {
        RemoveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Remove);
    }

    private void Remove()
    {
        // Do something here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, however I tried `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:ExplorerControl}, Mode=FindAncestor},Path=RemoveCommand}` without result. I cannot use your second approach because I need to create to process the command in the MainWindowViewModel where my Explorer control is.

Comment: Can you add more code so I can replicate yours and see what the DataContext is?

Comment: I just add it, The dataContext is a Node, because if I put the command in the node it works.

Comment: Thanks for your work, The snoop tool help me a lot with debugging.