# Binding DependencyProperty in codebehind to CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to send property thats set by dp to my viewmodel (bound via datacontext) via command parameter a Dependency Property in the code behind of my view. The property (ParentUserControl) seems to be initialized correctly when breaking into it, however I can't seem to be able to send it. I've tried the two bindings below

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Command="{Binding CommandTest}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding ParentUserControl, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyView}}}" />
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

and

```
<ContextMenu>
    <MenuItem Command="{Binding CommandTest}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding ParentUserControl, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
</ContextMenu>
```

I'm using mvvmlight relay commands as shown below however the parameter pased in the method test() is always null

```
CommandTest = new RelayCommand<object>(x => test(x));
```

This is the dependency property attached in the code behind of the view:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ParentUserControlProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ParentUserControl", typeof(UserControl), typeof(MyView), new PropertyMetadata(default(UserControl)));

public UserControl ParentUserControl
{
    get { return (UserControl) GetValue(ParentUserControlProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ParentUserControlProperty, value); }
}
```

Comment: The `ContextMenu` breaks the Visual Tree, you can bridge the gap using `PlacementTarget` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668654/relativesource-binding-from-a-tooltip-or-contextmenu).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what I'm looking for, the command is already bound to the viewmodel and works fine, it's command parameter I'm having difficulties with

Comment: Although I did try it on CommandParameter, but had no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
<DataGrid
    Tag="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MyView}}}">
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="{Binding CommandTest}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.ParentUserControl, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:ContextMenu}}}" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
</DataGrid>
```

You bind the Tag of the `DataGrid` to `MyView`. In `MenuItem` you seatch for the `ContextMenu`, use its `PlacementTarget` (which is the DataGrid) and its `Tag` (which is the `MyView`).

Answer (score 0):

Use the name of the View to find the parameter

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyViewName, Path=ParentUserControl}"
```

Also add a dummy binding of `ParentUserControl` on the `MyView` with its ViewModel (and check if it is working at that level).
I mean, try create a `UserControl Parent` property on the View Model, binding the dependency of MyView and then try

```
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MyViewName, Path=DataContext.Parent}"
```

In the latter case, since it's already in the View Model, maybe you don't even need the parameter. By the way, from a MVVM design pattern perspective, you should not pass a Control as a parameter to the ViewModel...

Comment: I've also tried this but unfortunately it still passes in null

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by dummy binding, could you explain more please.