# Catel - CommandManager not passing CommandParameter

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, catel

I have a Catel Application with a "MainView" and some nested views inside.
The nested views have a `ListView` with some items which have a `ContextMenu` with some `MenuItems`.

In the ViewModel of the MainView I've created a `TaskCommand<object>` which will do something with the passed parameter. This passed parameter should be the currently `SelectedItem` of the `ListView`. This Command is being registered globally to the `ICommandManager`.

If I click on the `MenuItem` with the bound Command from the `ICommandManager`, the passed parameter will always be `null`.

Here the relevant code:

*NestedView.xaml*:

```
<catel:UserControl
  x:Name="UserControl"
  x:Class="My.NameSpace.Views.View"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:catel="http://catel.codeplex.com">

...
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            BorderThickness="0"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="2.5"
                   Text="{Binding Description}">
          <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
              <MenuItem Header="Do Stuff"
                        Command="{catel:CommandManagerBinding DoStuffCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItem, ElementName=UserControl}" />
              ...
            </ContextMenu>
          </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
      </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
...
</catel:UserControl>
```

*MainViewModel.cs*:

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase {
    ...

    public ICommand DoStuffCommand { get; }

    public MainViewModel(ICommandManager commandManager, IUIVisualizerService uiVisualizerService, IMessageService messageService)
    {
      ...

      DoStuffCommand = new TaskCommand<object>(OnDoStuffCommandExecute);

      commandManager.CreateCommand(nameof(DoStuffCommand));
      commandManager.RegisterCommand(nameof(DoStuffCommand), DoStuffCommand, this);
    }

    private async Task OnDoStuffCommandExecute(object parameter)
    {
      // command needs to be in the MainViewModel because there will be some modification on the MainView based on parameter (adding tabs, etc)
      Debugger.Break();
    }

    ...
}
```

If you need more code, I can post this as well but this should be enough.

I Also took a look into Catel's `CommandManager` implementation and found this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="commandName">Name of the command.</param>
    /// <exception cref="ArgumentException">The <paramref name="commandName"/> is <c>null</c> or whitespace.</exception>
    /// <exception cref="InvalidOperationException">The specified command is not created using the <see cref="CreateCommand"/> method.</exception>
    public void ExecuteCommand(string commandName)
    {
        Argument.IsNotNullOrWhitespace("commandName", commandName);

        lock (_lockObject)
        {
            Log.Debug("Executing command '{0}'", commandName);

            if (!_commands.ContainsKey(commandName))
            {
                throw Log.ErrorAndCreateException<InvalidOperationException>("Command '{0}' is not yet created using the CreateCommand method", commandName);
            }

            _commands[commandName].Execute(null);
        }
    }
```

I assume that this method will be called if I click the `MenuItem` and would explain the behavior.

Is there any proper solution/workaround for passing a (bound) parameter to my `OnExecute` method?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I found the solution, but it's actually a little bit strange.

First of all swap the order of `Command={...}` and `CommandParamter={...}` (like Geert said).
Then after a lot of failing I got it working: Just pass into the `CommandParameter`-Binding the Markup and nothing else. So my XAML code for the `MenuItem` looks like this:

```
  <MenuItem Header="Do Stuff"
            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
            Command="{catel:CommandManagerBinding DoStuffCommand}"/>
```

## EDIT:

Ok now I got a solution (I think). The way above works most the time but may run into problems as @mm8 points out.

So I googled even more and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3668699 (see Update 2)

The in this answer given solution works now fine for me, because I can bind directly to my `ViewModel` and get the needed values via binding.

Comment: You can't bind to ElementName=UserControl in a MenuItem of the ContextMenu because the ContextMenu and the UserControl reside in different element trees. The DataContext of the MenuItem that you bind to using Command="{Binding}" is the item that you click on the open the ContextMenu. This is not necessarily the same as the currently selected item.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the `CommandParameter` binding *before* the command binding in xaml

   MenuItem Header="Do Stuff" 
       CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItem, ElementName=UserControl}"
       Command="{catel:CommandManagerBinding DoStuffCommand}"
2. Keep in mind that your binding context in the menu item is the **item**, not the **view model**. If you want to bind to the view model, you need to provide a name to the root grid and bind like this:

   ```
   CommandParameter="{Binding DataContext.SelectedItem, ElementName=rootGrid}"
   ```

Note that using `UserControl` is not working because the VM is set inside an internal grid (see the docs for an explanation why). So either use `UserControl.ViewModel` or `SomeInnerControl.DataContext`

Comment: I've changed the order of ```Command={...}``` and ```CommandParameter={...}``` but it still passes ```null```. I debugged the code and it seems like the ```Binding```-Expression doesn't get evaluated correctly. 

I've added a method in the code-behind of the View for the ```MenuItem```'s ```Click```-Event and the ```CommandParameter``` is always null. 

I have actually no idea what's wrong in this code