# WPF How to bind a command to the ContextMenu in RichTextBox?

Tags: wpf, binding, command, contextmenu, richtextbox

I've created **RichTextBox** control with **Menu** at the top side of **Window**. The **MenuItems** call Commands - It works perfectly. Then I try to create ContextMenu in the **RichTextBox** and want to call the same commands like in **MenuItems**.
So that, I bind the ContextMenu in the same way like **MenuItems**  but it throws the **NullReferenceException**.

What can be the reason. How should I bind the Command to the ContextMenu??

Below are the parts of my code

MenuItem code:

```
<MenuItem Name="FontSettings" Header="Font settings" Command="{Binding FontSettingsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainRichTbx}" />
```

RichTextBox code:

```
  <RichTextBox Name="MainRichTbx" TextBlock.LineHeight="0.1" Margin="5" >
             <RichTextBox.ContextMenu>
                 <ContextMenu>
                     <MenuItem Header="Font settings" Command="{Binding FontSettingsCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=MainRichTbx}" />
                 </ContextMenu>
             </RichTextBox.ContextMenu> 
   </RichTextBox>
```

That command which I want to execute:

> ```
>   private ICommand _FontSettingsCommand;
>           public ICommand FontSettingsCommand
>           {
>               get
>               {
>                   if (_FontSettingsCommand == null)
>                   {
>                       _FontSettingsCommand = new RelayCommand(
>                           argument => EditorFormat.SetFont(argument),
>                           argument => true
>                           );
>                   }
>                   return _FontSettingsCommand;
>               }
>           }
> ```

The method which I call within the Command:

```
public static void SetFont(object control)
    {
        FontDialog fontDialog = new FontDialog();

        if (fontDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            (control as System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox).FontFamily = new System.Windows.Media.FontFamily(fontDialog.Font.Name);
            (control as System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox).FontSize = fontDialog.Font.Size;
            (control as System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox).FontStyle = fontDialog.Font.Italic ? FontStyles.Italic : FontStyles.Normal;
            (control as System.Windows.Controls.RichTextBox).FontWeight = fontDialog.Font.Bold ? FontWeights.Bold : FontWeights.Regular;
        }
    }
```

And The RelayCommand class

```
   class RelayCommand : ICommand
     {
         private readonly Action<object> _Execute;
         private readonly Func<object, bool> _CanExecute;

         public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute)
         {
             if (execute == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");
             _Execute = execute;
             _CanExecute = canExecute;
         }

         public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
         {
             return _CanExecute == null ? true : _CanExecute(parameter);
         }

         public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
         {
             add
             {
                 if (_CanExecute != null) CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value;
             }
             remove
             {
                 if (_CanExecute != null) CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value;
             }
         }

         public void Execute(object parameter)
         {
             _Execute(parameter);
         }
     }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3668654/relativesource-binding-from-a-tooltip-or-contextmenu/3668699#3668699

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution which I think works, binding to the PlacementTarget of the context menu.

```
<RichTextBox Name="MainRichTbx" TextBlock.LineHeight="0.1" Margin="5" >
  <RichTextBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem Header="Font settings"
                Command="{Binding FontSettingsCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget}" />
    </ContextMenu>
  </RichTextBox.ContextMenu>
</RichTextBox>
```

However, the XAML designer underlines the CommandPamameter and shows the tooltip "RelativeSource is not in FindAncestor mode". Nevertheless it seems to work.

**Edit**

Adding Mode=FindAncestor seems to fix the error message. I don't know if it has any effect on the behavior.

```
<RichTextBox Name="MainRichTbx" TextBlock.LineHeight="0.1" Margin="5" >
  <RichTextBox.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
      <MenuItem Header="Font settings"
                Command="{Binding FontSettingsCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacementTarget}" />
    </ContextMenu>
  </RichTextBox.ContextMenu>
</RichTextBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because the binding can't find your text box.

This happens because the `ContextMenu` is not part of the visual tree so can't find your Text Box for the `CommandParameter`.
The best way around this is to not use the `CommandParameter` at all, but use a variable in your ViewModel (such as `SelectedTextBox`).

However, you can get a working (but slightly uglier) solution by naming your `ContextMenu` and setting its NameScope in the View's constructor:

```
NameScope.SetNameScope(myContextMenu, this);
```

This should then work correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the respond but I do the app according with MVVM and don't want to use any code-behind