# Cannot find source for binding with reference in nested Style / DataGrid DataTemplates

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have a `Control` (`ZlsUnitBrowserActive`) with two `DependencyProperties` `MaxWidthIdentifier`/`PropertiesDataTemplate`. I'm stuck when try to bind these two properties in the `Style`:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='PlcFramework.Zls.Production.ProductionControls.ZlsUnitBrowserActive', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=PropertiesDataTemplate; DataItem=null; target element is 'DataGridTemplateColumn' (HashCode=30225241); target property is 'CellTemplate' (type 'DataTemplate')

```xml
<Style TargetType="productionControls:ZlsUnitBrowserActive">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="productionControls:ZlsUnitBrowserActive">
                    <DataGrid>
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate 
                                    MaxWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=productionControls:ZlsUnitBrowserActive}, Path=MaxWidthIdentifier}"
                                    CellTemplate="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=productionControls:ZlsUnitBrowserActive}, Path=PropertiesDataTemplate}"/>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Is there a special trick? Also tried by caching the `ZlsUnitBrowserActive` instance in `DataGrid.Tag` (see post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3668699/6229375), without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. The trick is to use a `"BindingProxy"`.

I didn't really understand exactly why I had to solve it this way. Maybe someone can give me an explanation or post a better solution.

```cs
public class BindingProxy : Freezable
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty;

    static BindingProxy()
    {
        DataProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Data), typeof(object), typeof(BindingProxy));
    }

    public object Data
    {
        get => GetValue(DataProperty);
        set => SetValue(DataProperty, value);
    }

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new BindingProxy();
    }
}
```

```xml
<Style TargetType="productionControls:ZlsUnitBrowserActive">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="productionControls:ZlsUnitBrowserActive">
                    <DataGrid>
                        <DataGrid.Resources>
                            <xamlHelper:BindingProxy x:Key="DataContextBindingProxy" Data="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/> 
                        </DataGrid.Resources>
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate 
                                    MaxWidth="{Binding Path=Data.MaxWidthIdentifier, Source={StaticResource DataContextBindingProxy}}"
                                    CellTemplate="{Binding Path=Data.MaxWidthIdentifier, Source={StaticResource PropertiesDataTemplate}"/>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you can't bind a property of a `DataGridColumn` to a visual ancestor using a `RelativeSource` is that the column itself is not part of the visual tree so it has no ancestors to bind to.

The `DataGrid` control is part of the visual tree though and the "BindingProxy" can be used to bind to and "capture" a `DataContext`, for example using a `RelativeSource` of the `DataGrid`.

Thomas Levesque has written a blog post that explains this in detail: https://thomaslevesque.com/2011/03/21/wpf-how-to-bind-to-data-when-the-datacontext-is-not-inherited/.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought that might be the reason 